# Opencart 1.5.5.1 how change link in admin order

Tags: opencart

opencart 1.5.5.1 how change on normal link? See on picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLuy4.jpg

link in administration order to edit items (admin/index.php?route=catalog/product/update&token=4d93b21563db6a6c5fe44b7c365c210b&product_id=54), this is bad, how change on normal link (index.php?route=product/product&product_id=54)

Answer (score 0):

```
$action = array();

            $action = array(
                'text' => [[Pass_text_value]],
                'href' => $this->url->link('catalog/product/update', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&product_id=' . [[Pass_product_id_here]] . $url, 'SSL')
            );
```

See this is the only way you should pass actions like EDIT from the controller to template. The whole link will not be displayed but only the passed text.

If you are passing more than one instances to template then put these whole code inside your foreach loop and `change $action = array(` to `$action[] = array(`.

Comment: Thanks! I check later.